# What is Address Family?

Tags: sockets, network-programming

When I read about socket programming, I get to know that AF_ stands for Address Family. But literally, a family should have many members. So, what are the members of, say, AF_INET address family?

In my opinion, I think it would be more appropriate to say Address **Type** than Addresss **Family**. Also this applies to PF (Protocol Family).

Thanks.

Comment: **Type** could mean different things; a broadcast address is one type, a multicast address is another type, etc.

Comment: I agree. I am also confused by the choice of words sometimes, and AF was one of them. I guess there might be some historical reasons but I don't know. Anyway, in such situations, I'll try to figure out so they are aligned with my understanding conceptually. But if I can't, I'll just accept the terminology.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Members of `AF_INET` address family are IPv4 addresses.

Members of `AF_INET6` address family are IPv6 addresses.

Members of `AF_UNIX` address family are names of Unix domain sockets (`/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` is an example).

Members of `AF_IPX` address family are [IPX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internetwork_Packet_Exchange) addresses, and so on.

I don't think you really need to distinguish between *family* and *type* here. These are merely synonyms; except that *family* looks more specialized, well-suited for this purpose, whilst *type* is much overloaded, way too general word.

Ultimately, it's a convention. There's just so much literature using "address family" that it's well-established terminology, by decades if not human lifetimes.

Comment: So, when should one plan to add/create a new address family type(AF_) ? Any criteria for this ? I work in networking industry, and see AF_<XXX> sockets register messages where XXX are non standard names.

Comment: @Abnishek network addressing is OSI Level 3 function; so whenever you invent/introduce/experiment with a new L3 protocol (which basically means: any IP alternative) — you'll also need a new address family and a new `AF_<XXX>` constant.

Answer (score 18):

```
  Name                   Purpose                 
   AF_UNIX, AF_LOCAL      Local communication              
   AF_INET                IPv4 Internet protocols        
   AF_INET6               IPv6 Internet protocols
   AF_IPX                 IPX - Novell protocols
   AF_NETLINK             Kernel user interface device    
   AF_X25                 ITU-T X.25 / ISO-8208 protocol 
   AF_AX25                Amateur radio AX.25 protocol
   AF_ATMPVC              Access to raw ATM PVCs
   AF_APPLETALK           Appletalk                      
   AF_PACKET              Low level packet interface
```

Comment: Where is the source for this? Seems like a pretty nice and extensive list.

Comment: @sarangj You can find them in the [Address Family (7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/address_families.7.html) manpage.