# How can I make a ssh connection to my server without the IP address?

Tags: ssh

I created a public SSH key on my local computer and added it to my github account.
Now I want to connect to my server (online) via terminal, in order to clone my git project to the server of my provider.
In an online tutorial to connect they suggest:

```
 ssh root@< IP-ADDRESS OF THE SERVERS>
```

But in my server settings I can online find the following data:
SSH-Hostname,SSH-Username,SSH-Port,SSH Fingerprint

Is it possible to connect also with Hostname and Username? Because I cannot find the ip address of my provider.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure how this question has _anything_ to do with git _at all_.

Comment: @tkausl I want to clone my git project to my server

Comment: Once logged into the server, try cloning the repo `git clone ssh@github.com/username/repo.git`?

Comment: Is your question about cloning a Git repository, or connecting to a machine using SSH? Your title says the former, but the body says the latter.

Comment: @evolutionxbox how can I log in?

Comment: Logging into a server using ssh isn't a programming question, I found this article which may help https://www.howtogeek.com/311287/how-to-connect-to-an-ssh-server-from-windows-macos-or-linux/

Comment: @ndc85430 ah ok, now I understand.

Comment: @evolutionxbox That is the point, it is not working that way

Comment: Ask the ssh log in question on https://superuser.com/. Once logged in, clone the repo using the ssh link on github.com

Comment: To answer your question: if the hostname resolves to an IP address, yes.

Comment: @tkausl: it's not about Linux or terminals either :-) and it's only sort-of-vaguely about ssh, when it comes to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really on topic here (stackoverflow), but I'll put in a quick answer anyway: ssh makes a *network connection* to an ssh server, therefore ssh needs a *network address* for the server.  This need not be an *IP* address, except for one other issue, which is that the ssh protocol is defined as a TCP protocol and TCP runs over IP (v4 or v6).

That said, almost all networking systems have a mechanism for translating a *host name* to a *set of addresses* (some of which may be IP addresses; others might be XNS or IPX or some such: see [What is Address Family?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4976897/1256452)).  So you just need `user@host`, and something—OS and/or library dependent—will look up the proper IP address.  You can leave off the `user@` part in some cases.

If (this is a pretty big "if") your system *can't* translate the host name to an IP address, or does it incorrectly, *then* you can resort to a raw IP address.  This bypasses the translation step.  If you don't *trust* your translation software, you can do this intentionally.

Comment: Very good explaination!